# Visual Studio Code + suggest the available value in CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio, autocomplete, sass, autosuggest

Does Visual Studio Code have a option for suggest the available value for the CSS attribut ?

Example

**justify-content**: ( available value ) center | flex-end | flex-start | space-around | space-between

Example ( Bracket )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Emmet support is built in to VS Code and provides auto suggestions. See this article on a recent upgrade to Emmet 2.0 for more [info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet).